# Number of passwords with non repeated characters in alphabetical order

Tags: combinatorics

Each user on a computer system has a password, which is ten characters long, where each character is lowercase letter of an alphabet of 27 letters. Only different letters can be used and only in alphabetical order. How many possible passwords are there?

Why am I incorrect in reasoning that the answer is V(27,10) / P(10) = ((n!)/((n-m)!)) / n! = 30613591006480 / 3628800 = 8436285? (Maybe I'm not but my brute force attempt says so).

Comment: "In alphabetic order". Do you mean that if your alphabet is (a,b,c,d) that "abc" is allowed and "cab" not, because "cab" is not in alphabetic order? Or what is your definition of alphabetic order?

Comment: Just count the number of ways to choose the 10 letters from 27, since they must then appear in order. It looks as if that's what you are doing - but the V notation is new to me and I haven't checked the arithmetic.

Comment: Apologies around the notation, V means variations without repetitions, it is just : ((n!)/((n-m)!))

@Jasper you are right, abc is correct and acd is not.

Comment: @VíctorRomero: Why is acd not allowed? Does that mean only strings of $10$ consecutive letters are allowed? There would be only $27-10+1=18$ of those.

Comment: @EthanBolker is correct, if I get it the question right. You want to choose 10 different letters. This can be done in $\binom{27}{10}$ ways. Now you have 10 different letters, there is only one way to put them in alphabetic order. So the answer is $1\cdot \binom{27}{10} = 8436285$. This is the same answer as you found, so I think the question is mis-formulated.

Comment: Perhaps my brute force mechanism is wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No joriki, az is ok, aet is ok too. Just za is wrong or ca is wrong too.

Comment: @VíctorRomero Your answer 8436285 is correct and is the same as the comments given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting comment as answer at the OP's request:

Just count the number of ways to choose the 10 letters from 27, since they must then appear in order. It looks as if that's what you are doing - but the V notation is new to me and I haven't checked the arithmetic.